# Set custom filter plugin inside servicemanager config zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, filter, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have the following code in my application user form that creates the input filter for the `address2 element`.

```
  $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
  $inputFilter->add([
        'name' => 'address2',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => [
                ['name'=>'StringTrim'],
                ['name'=>'Administration\Filter\Ucwords']
        ]
    ]);
```

As you can see, I have the class name set as the name of the filter.

I get the following error:

`A plugin by the name "Administration\Filter\Ucwords" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Filter\FilterPluginManager`.

How do I get this filter into the `servicemanager configuration` ?

**NOTE**

I want to set this using configuration, not executing a call from within the module class so I can say `Ucwords` instead of the full class name inside the filter config.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration looks correct to me. The only issue here is that you have made a typo error when specifying filter name (`Administration\Filter\Ucwords`). Make sure that such class exists and it can be autoloaded.

I also strongly suggest you to specify the class constant (for fully qualified class name resolution) instead of string, e.g.

```
...
['name' => Administration\Filter\Ucwords::class]
...
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the class to the service manager configuration? Id prefer to do that than explicitly declare the class name

Answer (score 0):

**For ZF3**

**Assuming** that your `Ucwords` filter is implementing `Zend\Filter\FilterInterface`. You can then make **custom filter** available in the specific place in your application by adding it to `FilterPluginManager` and `FilterChain`. If any **filter** that you are attaching to the `FilterChain` must be known to `FilterPluginManager`. That is the main point to keep in mind.

**N.B.** However you can create a factory instead of a closure.

**Method 1**

Put the following code in the `module.config.php`.

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        CustomFilter::class => function($sm){         
            $filterChain = new \Zend\Filter\FilterChain;
            $filterChain->getPluginManager()
                        ->setInvokableClass('Ucwords', \Administration\Filter\Ucwords::class);
            return new CustomFilter($filterChain);
        },
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'CustomFilter' => CustomFilter::class,
    ],
],
```

**Method 2**

Make sure `Zend\Filter` is enabled via **`modules.config.php`** which is located in your application's config directory.

Now put the following code in the module's `module.config.php`.

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        CustomFilter::class => function($sm){
            $filterPluginManager = $sm->get('FilterManager');
            $filterChain = new \Zend\Filter\FilterChain();
            $filterChain->setPluginManager($filterPluginManager);

            return new CustomFilter($filterChain);
        },
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'CustomFilter' => CustomFilter::class,
    ],
],
'filters' => [
    'factories' => [
        Ucwords::class => InvokableFactory::class           
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'Ucwords' => Ucwords::class,
    ],
],
```

**Implementation**

Now create an instance of `Zend\InputFilter\Factory` (alias **InputFactory** here). Set the **FilterChain** object that you created and passed through the constructor of **CustomFilter** using a closure in the previous code. Create then input as needed using `Zend\InputFilter\Factory`'s **createInput()** method. Assign the custom **Ucwords** filter to where you need, (in this case, I added it to **title**). See the following code.

```
<?php
use Zend\Filter\FilterChain;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;

class CustomFilter extends InputFilter
{
    protected $filterChain;    

    public function __construct(FilterChain $filterChain)
    { 

        $this->filterChain = $filterChain;

        // Set the FilterChain object
        $factory = new InputFactory();
        $factory->setDefaultFilterChain($this->filterChain);

        $this->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(
                array(
                    // Here we go
                    'name' => 'Ucwords',
                ),  
            ),
        )));

        ...
    }
}
```