# cannot find service filter plugin Zend Framework

Tags: filter, configuration, zend-framework2, zend-framework3, zend-filter

Ive got the following configuration for my filters. this is used for zend framework's setup of service manager.

```
$filters = [
  'factories' => ['Administration\Filter\StripSpaces'=>'Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory']
  'aliases'   => ['StripSpaces'=>'Administration\Filter\StripSpaces']
];
return ['filters'=>$filters];
```

For the form usage

```
$inputFilter->add([
    'name'     => 'objectclassname',
    'required' => true,
    'filters'  => [
            ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
            ['name' => 'StripTags'],
            ['name' => 'StripNewlines'],
            ['name' => 'StripSpaces'] // here is where my StripSpaces alias is used
    ],
    'validators' => [                       
            [
             'name'    => 'StringLength',
             'options' => [
                'min' => 5,
                'max' => 255
              ],
         ]
     ],
]);
```

And here's the error when loading the form that uses this filter:

```
A plugin by the name "StripSpaces" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Filter\FilterPluginManager
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702914/set-custom-filter-plugin-inside-servicemanager-config-zend-framework

Comment: @AlainPomirol Why cant i just add it to the service manager and add an alias instead of doing all that work? they want me to add a custom filter and they have the same configurations

Comment: you will find an explanation in the documentation at https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-filter/filter-chains/#using-the-plugin-manager. A `FilterPluginManager` is attached to every `FilterChain` instance. Every filter that is used in a `FilterChain` must be known to the filtre plugin manager.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no filter called StripSpaces in ZF3.

Comment: I know its a filter i wrote i cant get it to work doing what i did

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have custom filters/validators within your InputFilter you should retrieve the `InputFilter` class from your `InputFilterManager` as in:

```
$serviceManager->get('InputFilterManager')->get(MyInputFilter::class);
```

Or use any alias instead of the FQCN, it's based on how you registered your inputFilters.

Why do I need to fetch my inputfilter from the manager? Due to the fact that when you create a new object, as in `new MyInputFilter()`, the `InputFilter\Factory` creates a new instance of the `InputFilterManager` class. This is not the applications `InputFilterManager` which contains your configuration, thus only the default Zend filters/validators. This is fine to use if you don't have any custom filters or validators you want to use.

When you use the applications `InputFilterManager` to fetch your inputfilter, it [updates the factory](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/blob/master/src/InputFilterPluginManager.php#L84%22updates%20the%20factory%22) by providing the applications `InputFilterManager` which contains a reference to the applications `ServiceManager`. And from your application `ServiceManager` it fetches the other managers for your filters and validators and [updates the chains](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/blob/master/src/InputFilterPluginManager.php#L102%22%20updates%20the%20chains%22) of the InputFilter Factory. So the InputFilter is aware of your custom filters/validators.

Note that you should update the way you setup your input filters. Do not setup your filters/validators in the `__construct()` as the chains are not yet updated and thus do not contain your custom filters/validators. Move your input filter configuration to the `public function init()` which is called from the `InputFilterManager`, which [initializes](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/blob/master/src/InputFilterPluginManager.php#L125%22intializes%22) your InputFilter class.